# Tags for hospital & healthcare - various different attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap

I have several datasets  - datasets derived from the Living Atlas at Esri

see https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/en/home/

Datasets from hospitals

Canada
USA
Germany

**Canada**
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=bf1249f3c9a64bcc809a6912c19c966d

**US-Hospitals:**
map:  https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/53b8031b906e43c4a4dbcf2250022ca0_0?geometry=-88.345%2C-8.577%2C-139.322%2C74.544
data: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=53b8031b906e43c4a4dbcf2250022ca0

**German hospitals** (hospital):

- Map: https://npgeo-corona-npgeo-de.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/348b643c8b234cdc8b1b345210975b87_0
- Daten: https://npgeo-corona-npgeo-de.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/348b643c8b234cdc8b1b345210975b87_0/data

**note**: these datasets have different attributes.

Why is this so?

see below some details

https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/en/home/

Canada
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=bf1249f3c9a64bcc809a6912c19c966d

> The Open Database of Healthcare Facilities (ODHF) is a collection of
> open data containing the names, types, and locations of health
> facilities across Canada. It is released under the Open Government
> License - Canada. The ODHF compiles open, publicly available, and
> directly-provided data on health facilities across Canada. Data
> sources include regional health authorities, provincial, territorial
> and municipal governments, and public health and professional
> healthcare bodies. This database aims to provide enhanced access to a
> harmonized listing of health facilities across Canada by making them
> available as open data. This database is a component of the Linkable
> Open Data Environment (LODE).
>
> Data sources and methodology The inputs for the ODHF are datasets
> whose sources include regional health authorities, provincial,
> territorial and municipal governments, and public health and
> professional healthcare bodies. These datasets were available either
> under one of the various types of open data licences, e.g., in an open
> government portal, or as publicly available data. In certain cases,
> data were obtained directly from administrative sources. Details of
> the sources used are available in the ODHF metadata.
>
> The data sources used do not deploy a uniform classification system.
> The ODHF harmonizes facility type by assigning one of three types to
> each health facility. This was done based on the facility type
> provided in the source data as well as using other research carried
> out for the purpose. The facility types used in the ODHF are:
> ambulatory health care services, hospitals, and nursing and
> residential care facilities. However, alternative medicine (e.g.,
> herbalists) and specialist areas (e.g., chiropractors, dentists,
> mental health specialists, etc.) are not in scope for the current ODHF
> version (version 1.0).
>
> The ODHF does not assert having exhaustive coverage and may not
> contain all facilities in scope for the current version. While efforts
> have been made to minimize these, facility type classification and
> geolocation errors are also possible. While all data are released on
> the same date, the dates as of which data are current depends on the
> update dates of the sources used.
>
> A subset of geo-coordinates available in the source data were
> validated using the internet and updated as needed. When latitude and
> longitude were not available, geocoding was performed for some sources
> using address data in the source. Some coordinates were also removed
> from the original sources when it was determined they were derived
> from postal codes or other aggregate geographic areas as opposed to
> street address.
>
> Deduplication was done to remove duplicates for cases where sources
> overlapped in coverage.
>
> This first version of the database (version 1.0) contains
> approximately 9,000 records. Data were collected by accessing sources
> between November 2019 and March 2020.
>
> The variables included in the ODHF are as follows:
>
> Index Facility Name Source Facility Type ODHF Facility Type Provider
> Unit Street Number Street Name Postal Code City Province or Territory
> Source-Format Street Address Census Subdivision Name Census
> Subdivision Unique Identifier Province or Territory Unique Identifier
> Latitude Longitude For more information on how the addresses and
> variables were compiled, see the metadata that accompanies the ODHF.
>
> This is a republishing of the data that is freely available from
> Statistics Canada at
> https://www.statcan.gc.ca/eng/lode/databases/odhf. Records that did
> not have a latitude and longitude value (about 1,500) were geocoded
> using the Esri World Geocoder. For more information on this data set
> please review the Statistics Canada metadata document.

Canada 1
Canada 2
USA
Deutschland

```
+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Canada 1 (ca 10000 recprds)  | Canada 2 (ca 10000 recprds)  | US  (ca.4400 records)  |                                              | Deutschland (ca. 2800 records) |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                              |                              |                        | example                                      |                                |
| index                        | Address_1                    | FID                    |                                              | OBJECTID                       |
| Name                         | City                         | OBJECTID               |                                              | Name                           |
| provider                     | County_Nam                   | Provider_N             |                                              | Einrichtung                    |
| ODHF facility type           | Emergency_                   | State_1                |                                              | Gesundheitsattribut            |
| unit                         | FID                          | County_Nam             |                                              | Gesundheitsattribut            |
| Street                       | Hospital_O                   | Hospital_T             | Acute Care  / Critical Access                | Spezialrichtung                |
| CSDname                      | Hospital_T                   | Hospital_O             | Proprietary  / Voluntary non-profit – Church | Betreiber                      |
| Prov                         | Name_new                     | Emergency_             |                                              | Betreibertyp                   |
| postal code                  | OBJECTID                     | ZipCode                |                                              | Telefon                        |
| CSDuid                       | PhoneNum                     | PhoneNum               |                                              | Website                        |
| Pruid                        | Provider_N                   | Address_1              |                                              | email                          |
| latitude                     | State_1                      | City                   |                                              | Fas                            |
| longitude                    | ZipCode                      | Name_new               | Howard Memorial Hospital                     | Adresse                        |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Adresse voll                   |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Straße                         |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Hausnummer                     |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Postleitzahl                   |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Stadt                          |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Hausname                       |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Stadtteil                      |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Unterbezirk                    |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Bezirk                         |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Provinz                        |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Bundesland                     |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Konfession                     |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Religion                       |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Notaufnahme                    |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Räume                          |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Betten                         |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Kapazität                      |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | Rollstuhlgerecht               |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | wikidata                       |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | wikipedia                      |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | ORIG_FID                       |
|                              |                              |                        |                                              | GlobalID                       |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Why is this so - why do we have such various different tags and attributes?

Comment: Datasets from different providers contain similar data, but they're different because they're different datasets/providers. Why would you expect that there would be only one way to collect data in different countries?

Comment: good day dear Vince - many thanks for steppin up the plate - geat to hear from you. Well convinced - i guess that youre right.  i have to admit that the different countries do map different!  - have a great day